Are shorter variants of machine instructions worth it?
I'm writing a JIT runtime, and I've started thinking about shorter variants of some instructions.
In x64 we can do at least two kinds of jumps: rel8 and rel32. The first one takes say 2 bytes (opcode + 8-bit offset) while the second one 5 bytes (opcode + 32-bit offset). Of course the second one can handle wider range of offsets.
Btw, I'm talking here about raw jumps, but this applies to conditional jumps as well.
The short jump seems to faster. Or rather that's what I've been told. And makes instructions shorter which nicely improves caching. However we still may need longer jumps. And decision on when to chose one requires additional processing. Which is either complicated or inefficient (in terms of compile time, which is important in the context of JITting), or both. The reason is that consecutive forward jumps affect each other depending on the length they take.
An alternative is to always use long jumps. Which makes code generation fairly simple.
So the question is: is using long jumps, even when valid short jump can be used, always inefficient? In theory it should be. However I've done some tests and I couldn't find any performance benefits from using short jumps. But maybe my tests were flawed.
Another idea is to choose short vs long, but keep the buffer as it is, without processing. So we generate all jumps as long first, and when detected that short can be used, use it and fill the remaining 3 bytes with nop instruction. Would that bring any benefit over long jumps? Again, my tests seem to show that long jumps are just as effective.
Maybe it depends on hardware? I've been testing this on my personal machine, some Ryzen 7 CPU. Although I'm mostly interested in modern CPUs.
Can anyone shed light on this?

// EDIT: Here's an explanation why "just pick shorter version when you have shorter jump" is actually not trivial at all. Consider the following sequence of instructions:
B:
...
jmp A
...
jmp B
...
A:
...

Say distance from jmp A to A is 100. So it fits in 2-byte short jump. And it is a forward jump. Now say distance from B to jmp B is 120. So it also fits in 2-byte short jump. And it is a backwards jump. Everything's fine, we write those relative distances to machine code. And so jmp A is translated into jmp 100 in machine code. Remember that machine code operates in bytes, not in labels. But no sane language will operate in bytes, not even assemblers do.
But what if jmp B is actually 500 bytes distant from B? Then it means it has to fit into 5-byte jump. But then we have 3 additional bytes between jmp A and A, and so we need to patch jmp A in machine code. Previously we've emitted jmp 100 but now we need jmp 103.
Moreover, if we put 10 such jmp B instructions between jmp A and A, then now we need to patch jmp A into jmp 130. But 130 doesn't fit 8-bit (signed) integer. And so jmp A has to be widened to 5 bytes. But then all those jmp B need to be patched as well (because jmp A lies between B and jmp B). Oh, what a headache... Note that none of those problems exist if we emit long jumps only.
Solving that is either complicated or inefficient, or both. I'm linking an article that explains a potential solution, and how LLVM deals with it: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/01/03/assembler-relaxation I might actually implement it, but honestly I'm not even sure this is worth it. If I emit long (or rather: fixed size) jumps always, then emitting machine code is just simple, I don't need to deal with resizes and patching at all.

// EDIT 2:
Here's how I did my tests on both those variants. The code is in Rust. I use region lib for handling executable buffer, and then I do:
fn fill_buffer<T: Write>(
    buffer: &mut T,
    number_of_nops: i32,
    add: &[u8]) -> usize
{
    let mut write = |slice| {
        buffer.write_all(slice).unwrap();
    };

    write(&[0x48, 0x31, 0xC0]);  // xor rax, rax

    let mut counter = 0;

    write(add);  // jmp -> add
    counter += add.len();

    for _ in 0..number_of_nops {
        write(&[0x90]);  // nop
        counter += 1;
    }

    write(add);  // again jmp -> add
    counter += add.len();

    write(&[0x48, 0x39, 0xf8]);  // cmp rax, rdi
    counter += 3;

    counter += 6;
    let neg = (-(counter as i32)).to_le_bytes();
    write(&[0x0f, 0x8c]);  // jl rel32 (to the initial jmp, i.e. loop it)
    write(&neg);

    write(&[0xc3]);  // ret
    return counter+4;
}

This function will be called with one of the two following binaries (as add argument):
const SHORT_ADD: &[u8] = &[
    0xeb, 0x02,  // jmp (rel8) +2
    0x90,  // nop
    0x90,  // nop
    0x48, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x01,  // add rax, 1
];

const LONG_ADD: &[u8] = &[
    0xe9, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // jmp (rel32) +2
    0x90,  // nop
    0x90,  // nop
    0x48, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x01,  // add rax, 1
];

So basically I create the following function:
fn func(rdi: i64) -> i64 {
    let mut result = 0;
    while result < rdi {
        result += 1;  // fancy jmp->add here
        // nops here
        result += 1;  // fancy jmp->add here
    }
    return result;
}

and the difference between variants is that the second one uses 6 bytes more (twice +3 bytes due to long jump). And then main:
fn main() {
    const SIZE: usize = 1 << 14;
    for i in 80..400 {
        unsafe {
            let number_of_nops = i;
            // Allocate executable memory
            let mut alloc = region::alloc(SIZE, region::Protection::READ_WRITE_EXECUTE).unwrap();

            // Convert to vec, which implements Write
            let buffer = alloc.as_mut_ptr::<u8>();
            let mut vec = Vec::from_raw_parts(buffer, 0, SIZE);
            let result = fill_buffer(&mut vec, number_of_nops, LONG_ADD);
            forget(vec);  // Don't run vec's destructor

            // Convert to function pointer
            let func: extern "sysv64" fn(i64)->i64 = core::mem::transmute(buffer);

            // and time it
            let rdi = 50000000;
            let now = SystemTime::now();
            let a = func(rdi);
            let now2 = SystemTime::now();

            // Display results
            let diff = now2.duration_since(now).unwrap().as_millis();
            println!("Result: {a}, RDI: {rdi}, number_of_nops: {number_of_nops}, took me: {diff}");
        }
    }
}

Finally I run those functions with RDI set to 50000000 so they loop enough times. Then I measure. The code increases in size, but not in complexity. At some point it will cross cache size limit.
The results are inconclusive. In fact the long variant is sometimes faster. The difference doesn't seem to be greater than 5%, but in both directions.

At first approximation, smaller code = better cache utilisation = faster. But beyond that, this is going to depend entirely on microarchitectural details. Agner's optimization manuals are a helpful guide to x86 based microarchitectures: https://agner.org/optimize/

@amon yes, that's what I thought: smaller code = better cache utilisation. But in practice I just couldn't create  sophisticated enough code where that actually mattered. And so I started doubting that claim.

"Worth it" is subjective, no? — especially as you have JIT compile performance and generated code quality to balance..

On older CPUs you may not have a choice. Many of the 8 bit processors had only short conditional branch instructions. I'm unsure if this applies to modern processors.

Before you wring your hands over this too much be sure you understand this.

@candied_orange what do you mean? How is branch prediction relevant here?

@kiwiron perhaps I wasn't clear enough, but I am interested in x64 cpus only. For the purpose of the question anyway. These have to have both variants.

Please tell us more about the usage of your JITer? How big are the pieces of code it needs to translate? How long is the translated code retained? Does it get run many times?

@JohnDallman it is supposed to serve as backend for a certain language. The language is supposed to replace Lua as a scripting language for games. And so code can be arbitrarily large, and likely retained for the whole duration of gameplay. JITted functions are likely to be called many times, I consider tiered compilation. It is supposed run many times, compilation is supposed to be done lazily, on demand. Something close to C#, but not C# (for other reasons).

I really hopped this question would do better here. Don’t have time to research this properly. But Im guessing the extra time needed to add to the IP when long jumping is nothing next to a cache miss. So my concern is how much bigger the instructions become. But that’s a function of how often jump instructions get used. Which I don’t know off the top of my head. I know move is used most frequently. I’m thinking of short jump as a compressed long jump. So this is a classic time space trade off. The question is are you trading enough to cause a cache miss?  That’s when added space kills time.

Well, how often short jump instructions get used. Since that’s what we’re talking about changing.

@candied_orange as I said in my question: I wasn't able to produce an example where actually short jumps outperform long. And I tried very long examples, with loops that don't fit cache, etc. But also those examples where somewhat realistic, filled with other instructions that actually do something. Maybe one can create a pathological example with jumps only. But honestly currently I doubt even that. But if you can produce one I will be more than happy to try it out. Finally, I still don't see what this has to do with branch prediction at all.

@freakish I’m analyzing the problem in a completely different way than you are. Which is making this hard to explain. An example of all jumps is meaningless to me. What I’m looking at is if you replace all short jumps with long jumps how much bigger will that make the code were jumping around in?  Since long jumps are bigger instructions. More specifically, how much more frequent will that make a cache miss? I’m concerned about that because a cache miss costs so much more time then adding up the extra bytes of a few long jumps.

@candied_orange I understand what you are saying. My point is that adding those extra bytes doesn't seem to affect performance negatively. Especially since a typical code is not dominated by jumps. You say that cache miss costs. Well, apparently it does not. At least not in this context. Or at least I don't see it.

@freakish oh a cache miss definitely costs. That isn't the question. The question is, if you only use long jumps, which will expand the code size, how much more likely are you making a cache miss. I ask, not because I've tested this. But because I want to be sure your testing takes it into account. It's the sort of thing that is easy to overlook. A cache miss costs a lot of time. Expanding the jumps grows the size of the binary code, a little. Without data I can't tell you if that's significant with typical code. What I'm arguing here is that optimizing on modern processors is not trivial.

@freakish if you can show that despite the significant cost of a cache miss the expansion of size of the binary is small enough that the increase of frequency of cache misses caused by it is small enough to be considered trivial then I'll be much more confident that this is an affordable simplification.

@candied_orange I've updated the question with the test I've made. Feel free to comment on it.

Java byte code has variants. Like (from memory) “load variable at index 1”, “At index 2”, “at index 10”, “at index n”. Making your bytecode smaller may have small performance benefits.
Whether it is enough benefits for the complexity is up to you.
For jump instructions: Usually you produce single byte jumps, and if the jump distance is too long, you make the instruction longer instead. And repeat until everything fits.

The problem is that "making instruction longer instead" is not a simple task. When generating code we don't know the exact place we need to jump. This is especially true for forward jumps. And especially when multiple jumps are involved, each affecting each other (if I decide to make jump X longer, then previous jump may have to be altered as well, if it points at something beyond X). I have a rough idea of an algorithm that calculates that. But it requires allocations. With a fixed length jumps I don't allocate much, which makes code generation very fast. Again, important in context of JIT.

It’s easy. Generate the code with all jumps and length unknown. Initially make all jumps short. Find all those that jump too far for a short branch, make them long branches. Repeat in case some branch distances are longer now until all branches fit.

You cannot generate code with jumps unknown. What does it even mean? Normally when you emit machine code you allocate space for jump instruction and then patch it with concrete value once it is calculated (once remaining instructions are emitted and encoded). You cannot then just "change short to long" because you don't have that space anymore. You can of course enlarge the instruction, but then you have to move entire remaining buffer. But that affects other jump instructions. For example if later you jump backwards, then that jump has to be patched, because now we have 3 more bytes.

You just record “instruction 3, 12 and 25 are branches”. Then you guess they all fit into two bytes. Then check all branch distances under this assumption and mark those that don’t fit as four bytes. Finally you generate the code with all branches the correct size. The buffer is instructions, not bytes.

Resizing one instruction affects other, so they require patching. It is not simple to implement. And it likely requires additional allocations. I've updated my question. It addresses this issue now.

@freakish: "It is not simple to implement." - well, what is simple to implement or not may be opinionated, but what gnasher729 suggested sounds simple and straightforward to implement for me. It is essentially the same approach as the one described in the assembler-relaxation article you gave a link to. Of course, it needs a multi-pass code generation, where each pass puts the intermediate code into a buffer, until the jmp distances won't change any more. What I noone can tell you is, ... (1/2)

... (2/2) whether this extra compilation effort will pay off, since it depends on how often the compiled code will be executed., and how much the rest of the program can use the extra cache    What I would do if I were in your shoes: implement the relaxation (which is probably easier than you think) and allow this feature to be enabled or disabled. Then collect data about the behaviour of both approaches empirically.

@DocBrown well, simple or not might be opinionated. But less performant algorithm, requiring more allocations is a fact. Also, if you see the same algorithm that I found in his comments than great. I don't see it at all, and the answer doesn't even address the main concern - which is whether long jumps are really less performant or is it a myth? Hence the downvotes I suppose (even though I did not downvote it).

@freakish: well, I perfectly agree to what you wrote about this answer (disclaimer: one downvote was from me). Still I think gnasher729 has a point in the former comments above: the implementation of an algo which tries to start with all short jumps and then replaces them iteratively with long jumps until all jumps are valid is not as complicated as you might think it is (especially your last edit gave me this impression). Hence, when you ask "is it worth to implement it", I would say "try it out, it will probably not take several weeks of your time".

@freakish: ... and in regards to performance of long vs. short jumps: I made a look into the source mentioned by amon (Agner's optimization manual). I did not check all of the tables inside, just scanned a few. My impression is that for the older CPU architectures, it made the huge difference, for the newer ones it does not. Still there is this saving in bytes, hence better cache utilization. If that's "worth enough" for you you will have to decide by yourself.

@DocBrown the problem is that compilation time is important, especially in JIT context. As far as I can see, the relaxation algorithm not only requires allocations but is also quadratic in the number of jumps (we need to recalculate all jumps whenever a jump needs widening). In pessimistic case anyway. While using fixed size jumps is a straightforward code generation. On the other hand LLVM seems to implement it (for its JIT engine as well) and I checked that at least C# also emits short jumps. So maybe it is less relevant than I think.

@freakish: in one pass of the relaxation, one will only require to recalculate the jumps which are not identified as long jumps, and only in the interval of instruction +/- 256 bytes before and after the modified jumps from the former pass. That does not even lead to quadratric behaviour in the worst case, and in any real world case, I would expect only one or two passes necessary in most cases. But sure, you don't get this optimization for free, and if the gain in cache mem will pay off depends solely on the specific code optimized. ...

... there is no easy answer saying you "this will save more cycles than it costs" except from "try this out, maybe make it optional for the user, or maybe find some nifty algorithm which is capable to decide by itself at runtime whether this optimization could be worth it".

I did this. Nothing was allocated, and you might have been able to construct quadratic cases, but in reality the time was not measurable.  Slightly more difficult: Some processors had no long conditional branches. So instead of a long conditional branch, you needed a short conditional branch around a long unconditional branch. Sometimes there was an unconditional branch close enough to reach.
